# MySql сделать запрос из трех БД

Tags: mysql, select

у меня есть три БД

1. dash_1
2. dash_2
3. dash_3

у всех таблиц одинаковые таблицы и столбцы

мой запрос

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS kol FROM `jobs` WHERE `DEALDATE`='2023-10-24'
```

чтобы посмотреть данные по дням я каждый раз меняю БД чтобы посмотреть количество работ

как мне сделать запрос чтобы объединить три БД

чтобы было вот такой ответ

| BD | kol |
| --- | --- |
| dash_1 | 12 |
| dash_2 | 5 |
| dash_3 | 9 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбирая из таблицы вы можете указать, в какой бд эта таблица находится.
Например так:

```
    SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `mydb1`.`jobs`  WHERE `DEALDATE`='2023-10-24'
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `mydb2`.`jobs` WHERE `DEALDATE`='2023-10-24'
```

Comment: дату еще можно впихнуть в переменную `SET @dd = '2023-10-24'` и использовать в запросе `dealdate = @dd`

Comment: откатили мою правку коли, то поясните, как вы в этих результатах поймете какая строка к какой БД относится? и зачем придумывать какие то свои названия БД, если в вопросе уже даны конкретные?

Comment: @teran Если вы считатете что ответ должен быть другим - создайте свой ответ. По моему мнению именно данный ответ - без конкретных частных деталей автора - во первых проще всего дает понять куда вставять имя бд и как обединить с другой бд. а во вторых делает ответ более универсальным и другие поьзователи могут им воспользоваться.